# Revert Unix installation to fresh install

Tags: ubuntu, unix

Let's say I have a fresh install of a Unix variant (Ubuntu, for instance), then I install different packages and edit some config files (php.ini, nginx.conf, etc.).

Now say I want to revert Ubuntu to the state it was when it was freshly installed. How can I achieve this?

(The reason I want to do this is to practice and experiment setting up Unix installations, so it's important that the starting point is the same every time.)

Is it as simple as just uninstalling all "apt" packages and keeping copies of the originals of all config files I plan to edit?

Or does software installation leave behind files or change settings that are not reverted?

Comment: Why not just use a virtual machine instead, make snapshots and roll back when needed?

Comment: One approach is to make a system image using something like `dd`, `partimage` etc. You can make and restore the image using a boot-CD or bootable USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aptitude to uninstall what it installs and if you don't install too much you may even get back to square one. There is also the Janitor that will give you an idea of what would need removed. Read up on Aptitude package management.

But what you really want is VirtualBox. It is free, without restrictions and allows you to create a base install of Ubuntu or whatever you want and CLone / Snapshot that new install. Then you go ahead and hammer that virtual machine while learning. Once you have had enough you go back to the Cloned image and your back on the first base install once again. It is too easy and free plus your joining the rest of the movement. :-)

Comment: What a nice reply! The snapshot thing was brilliant. Thanks! Can you send a link to this Janitor thing? Couldn't find it.